# How much information about $R-\mathrm{Mod}$ can be extracted from $\underline{R-\mathrm{Mod}}$ and $K_0(R)$?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, algebraic-k-theory

The question is in the title, so let me just repeat it:

> How much information about $R-\mathrm{mod}$ can be extracted from $\underline{R-\mathrm{mod}}$ and $K_0(R)$?

Here $\underline{R-\mathrm{mod}}$ stands for the stable module category, i.e. $R-\mathrm{mod}$ after killing all projective modules (and necessary morphisms). Let's say $R-\mathrm{mod}$ denotes the category of finitely presented modules.

I realize this is an open-ended question. I started with a more concrete one: Whether one can reconstruct (up to, say, Morita equivalence) $R-\mathrm{mod}$ using the two data. Obviously, this is not possible, since both the data are trivial ($R-\mathrm{mod}$ is some "$0$-category" and $K_0(R)=\mathbb{Z}$) for, say, two different fields, which are not Morita equivalent (never, as Qiaochu Yuan points out in comments).

I should probably mention that this question is not really motivated by anything - just on the first glance, it seems that, if one thinks of $K_0(R)$ as "compressing the information about fin.-gen. projectives", together with the stable module category it should still contain a lot of information.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Fields, or more generally commutative rings, are Morita equivalent iff they are isomorphic; the center of a ring is a Morita invariant.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks, I vaguely recall something like this, but wasn't sure about the exact statement, so I formulated it more loosely just to be safe. It does not change the point, however, which is that the whole category certainly isn't recostructible from the data.

Comment: Do you have any condition on your ring?  Stable module categories are rather crazy things usually.  For example, no method of constructing stable equivalences is known, apart from some special cases; in particular, reconstructing the ring behind such equivalence.  When we stablise, many structures of the category get destroyed - most notably exactness.  Anyway, I want to know what $K_0(R)$ means here, is it the group spanned by simple $R$-module or is it the one spanned by indec. projective $R$-module?  And what is the relation?

Comment: @Aaron : Well, I do not assume anything in particular on the ring, although If some extra assumptions help, I would be interested in that a well... (I realize this is really open-ended.) By $K_0(R)$ I mean the Grothendieck group of the monoid of finitely generated projectives with addition being the direct sum, so I guess it is the second one.

Comment: In that case, I think it is quite difficult to just use $K_0(R)$ to reconstruct $R$ - describing $R$ is the same as asking describing morphisms (in the ordinary module cat.) between the indec. projectives. $K_0(R)$ effectively forgets morphisms between indec projectives, how can we use information from $\underline{\mathrm{mod}}-R$ to get back the morphisms between them?  The problem when we try to reconstruct $R$ (or any stably equiv. ring) from $\underline{\mathrm{mod}}-R$ is that many maps got killed in the stable category, and you don't know which one got killed.